# How to retrieve missing defect ID from HPQC?

Tags: hp-quality-center, defects

I raised a defect in hpqc without a project tagged to the defect. I received the email of the defect raised but unable to find in HPQC listing.

How can I retrieve the defect to amend the project in ?

I tried searching for the defect, but resulted in defect does not exist.

I tried filtering without a project tagging but returned an empty list.